# Extra water line under sink?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

My house’s basement has a small kitchen area with a sink. I can’t figure out how to turn the water on to the sink. When I turn the valve on the left, I can run the sink but the third water line (which isn’t connected to anything) will run while I use the sink. When I turn on the valve on the right, the third water line runs no matter if I’m using the sink or not. Should I just cap this? Is this a refrigerator line?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for asking. And yes absolutely, it could be/could've been for a refrigerator, dishwasher, humidifier, poorly and illegally done toilet, standalone ice maker or even a trap wetter for a basement floor drain.

It was done by someone for a reason, so you should find out exactly what that reason was/is...since you now know where its local shutoff is in the case of service or emergency.

Only if you can pull the hose all of the way out to find its not connected at all should you cap it or change to a regular shutoff valve. If you don't need it and it's not currently doing anything, then go ahead and delete it.